# How to print pdf file which comes from firebase url in API response in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, printing

I want to print a pdf file and i am using

> syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer

to display the pdf and i need to print that displayed pdf file. Using print button i want that pdf going to start print.

I used this but its showing that 'Sorry, that didn't work'.

```
    await Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: (_) => 'Your Firebase Url' as Uint8List);
```

[image]

Comment: I want a solution for flutter app in which i need to print pdf file using pdf link.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer of this problem. Convert your string url to URI, please make sure you are adding http

http: ^0.13.4

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse('Your link here');
                        http.Response response = await http.get(uri);
                        var pdfData = response.bodyBytes;
                        await Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: (PdfPageFormat 
                        format) async => pdfData);
```